# Applying a phase shift to a coherent state vs a phase-space rotation (Mach-Zhender)

Tags: optics, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I'm having some trouble with the physical implementation of a phase vs rotation in phase-space for a coherent state.

Say I have a laser pulse which yields a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$, I then put that light into a Mach-Zender interferometer with a 50/50 beamsplitter to the point where one of the arms adds an additional phase of $\phi$, does that mean the state is

$|\frac{e^{i\phi}\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle$

or is it

$e^{i\phi}|\frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle$

I thought it was the first instance, but then thinking about it, I know MZIs can create destructive interference so when $\phi = \pi$, the output state has zero amplitude, which would suggest we get $|\alpha\rangle - |\alpha\rangle$ and not $|\alpha\rangle + |-\alpha\rangle$

Which leads me to my next question, if I had state $|\alpha\rangle$ and wanted to transform it to $|-\alpha\rangle$, how would I go about physically implementing that? Can it be done with a MZI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the first case: The MZ produces
$$ |\alpha\rangle\rightarrow \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \exp(i\phi)\alpha \right\rangle . $$
After the last beam splitter you then get
$$ |\alpha_{out}\rangle = \left| \frac{1}{2} \exp(i\phi)\alpha 
+ \frac{1}{2} \exp(-i\phi)\alpha\right\rangle 
= \left| \cos(\phi)\alpha \right\rangle . $$
For $\phi=\pi/2$, it would become the vacuum state $|0\rangle=|\text{vac}\rangle$.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense thanks. Do you know how one would physically produce the state $-|\alpha\rangle$?

Comment: A laser beam is generally regarded as a coherent state.

Comment: Right, but if I had a laser beam in the state $|\alpha\rangle$ how would I go about generating $-|\alpha\rangle$ or $e^{i\phi}|\alpha\rangle$?

Comment: Do you want to how how the coherent state is parameterized by the laser beam's properties? If you only care about the total power in the laser, then you can use $\alpha$ as a complex constant, which gives the number of photons as $|\alpha|^2$. If you are also interested in the beam profile, then you can allow the parameter to become an angular spectrum $\alpha(\mathbf{k})$.

Comment: I was just interested in, say you had a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$ and wanted to modulate it to $-|\alpha\rangle$ instead of $|-\alpha\rangle$, what would the physical process be? Maybe its inconsequential since its a global phase?

Comment: That would be a global phase and thus not physical.